# How to make linux to press a key everytime I write something

Tags: xdotool, autokey

As the title says, I want linux to autopress a key everytime I write something.

For example, whenever I type `_I` it should autopress `ctrl+j` ( if you're wondering why, it's for codeblocks :) )

I already tried AutoKey but didn't figure out how to do this with it ..

I saw now `xdotool` command that seems to do the right job, but it continuous keeps pressing `ctrl+j`, and I want only after I type `_I`.

I made this code:

```
#/bin/bash
while true; do
    xdotool key ctrl+j
    sleep 0.1
done
```

Now I think it should be something like

```
#/bin/bash
while true; do
    if pressed '_I'; then
        xdotool key ctrl+j
    fi
    sleep 0.1
done
```

But again, I don't know how to do that if.

Can somebody give me any suggestions please?

Thanks in advance!